# wp-admin .htaccess IP restricted

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, wp-admin

I noticed something weird after the latest WordPress update. I usually restrict access by IP via a simple `.htaccess` file in the `/wp-admin` folder. After the last update, I get a redirect loop when logging in. Anyone else noticed this and has the same problem?

I use this simple `.htaccess` line:

```
order deny,allow
```

Is the above deprecated after the last update?

What line should be used now to restrict WP admin access by IP?

Thanks for answering and taking the time to share your answer.

PS if i delete the lines/.htaccess file i get no redirect/loop error

Comment: Is this all that you have in your `.htaccess`? You would need to point out which IPs to deny (or all) as well as any to allow.

Comment: Welcome! Which version change are you referring to (your answer might be read by someone in the future!) Can you reproduce the behaviour with a minimal wordpress setup? (See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code of .htaccess and I used this below code for my side to restrict user to access wp-admin the only user can access whose IP added in file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^122\.169\.105\.107$ // Your IP
```

Hope this help!